# Finite State Automata for recognising consecutive characters

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I'm currently working on this question as part of some homework, it has me stumped.

[image: FSA Question]

I'm familiar with finite state automata (FSA), I know how they work and I've read everything I can find on Google, but nothing's helped me come any closer to a solution.

If I don't know the length of the input string, or I'm not searching for a particular pattern, how can I design a machine that will always land on the final state?

I've tried drawing some, but that always end up being a little off.

Comment: A.Schulz's answer gives you pretty much everything, but from the conceptual level, it may be worth recognising that you *are* looking for a particular pattern - $bb$. The difference is that you want to reject when you find it, rather than accept (and if you haven't found it, then everything is still okay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FSA should have three states:

- $q_a$ represents:  **last character was not a `b`, and no `bb` yet**
- $q_b$ represents:  **last character was a `b`, and no `bb` yet**
- $q_{bb}$ represents:  **there was already a `bb`**

Clearly, you start with $q_a$ and you accept in $q_a$ and $q_b$. Now try to figure out how to connect the states.